# Why occlusion culling isn't working?

Tags: unity

I've bought a 3d model from a 3d marketplace.

It is a big interior scene.

I've imported the single FBX into Unity, added some collider, changed materials (6-7 materials) etc. There are hundreds of child object/mesh:

[image]

Despite what my camera is looking, i noticed Unity is rendering 3-400K tris.

Why Occlusion Culling isn't working ? Maybe importing a single huge Fbx isn't the right practice ?

Thanks

This image is my player looking at a black wall... 360K tris rendered !!!!

[image]

Comment: How have you configured occlusion culling for your scene? It's not automatic, so you'll need to walk us through what steps you took so we can identify what you've missed

Comment: I didn't configure it: i just selected my Main Camera and flagged: Occlusion Culling

Comment: Right.. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OcclusionCulling.html

Comment: Can you walk us through the steps you followed based on that documentation?